# FBSDKLoginButton weird background

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook Login SDK and the `FBSDKLoginButton`. I initially used it on a white background but when I changed to a non-white background it exposed a very strange background image...

[image]

I'm not sure what I can change on it to hide that weird white background.

Has anyone dealt with this? How can I hide that white stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was so simple. I needed to set the button type to `Custom`. It was set to `System` by default.

I did that and now it looks perfect...

[image]

Thanks to @paulmorrislrd on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this looks like it is probably very frustrating. What version of the Facebook SDK are you using? Can you post a snippet of your code showing how the button is added to the view?  Also - if you can't get the FBSDK provided login button to work, it is possible to use a custom button with facebook.

Comment: The sdk is the latest release version through cocoa pods. The button is just a uibutton added in interface builder (no background) and set to be the Facebook login button subclass. Yeah, may have to create it myself.